# NoHostAvailable exception connecting to Cassandra from python

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra

I am obtaining an exception when trying to connect to my local instance of Cassandra from Python. I can connect to Cassandra with no problems using cqlsh. The version I am running is Cassandra 3.01 on ubuntu:

```
cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.1 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
```

The exception I obtain is below:

```
ERROR:cassandra.cluster:Control connection failed to connect, shutting down Cluster:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 840, in   cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect (cassandra/cluster.c:11146)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2088, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection.connect (cassandra/cluster.c:36955)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2123, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal (cassandra/cluster.c:37811)
 NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1':       InvalidRequest(u'code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured table schema_keyspaces"',), 'localhost': InvalidRequest(u'code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured table schema_keyspaces"',)
```

I have checked my cassandra.yaml file and it looks ok:

```
egrep 'rpc_port:|native_transport_port:' /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
native_transport_port: 9042
rpc_port: 9160
```

Anything else I can look at ? Suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to connect to a 3.0.1 server using an older install of cqlsh or you are (somehow) using an older python driver.

The error message you are getting:

```
(u'code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured table schema_keyspaces"',)
```

indicates that the client driver is attempting to get table metadata from the `schema_keyspaces` table which pre-dates 3.0. This information is now held in the `system_schema.keyspaces` table.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the case. I am using anaconda and this is the driver I have installed :
cassandra-driver          2.7.1                  nppy27_0    petercable
I suppose I should upgrade.
Do you know whether the 3.0.0 will be backward compatible and can connect to a Cassandra 2.x* instance?

Comment: Yes, it will. Drivers are backward compatible but not necessarily forward compatible. You might want to set the protocol version in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip install --upgrade cassandra-driver` to upgrade cassandra-driver.

You could type `python -c 'import cassandra; print cassandra.__version__'` to confirm the version of this driver.