# Error during inserting data: NoHostAvailable:

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I try to learn basics of Apache Cassandra. I found this simple example of application at https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_music_service_c.html

So I created a keyspace, then I created a table, and now I am trying to add some data to the database.

But when I try to Insert data I have got an error: "NoHostAvailable:" That's it. No more information.

[image: NoHostAvailable]

So far I've tried to update python driver ([NoHostAvailable exception connecting to Cassandra from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651000/nohostavailable-exception-connecting-to-cassandra-from-python)) but it didn't work.

What I do wrong? Or is it a problem with cqlsh?

Comment: Have you opened the required ports in your firewall?

Comment: @JimWright There is no firewall I think... I have a Virtual Machine. I am running cqlsh on this machine. I even created a tables via cqlsh. I cannot read or write data to this tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK. I've found the answer. The NetworkTopologyStrategy is not suited for running on a single node. After changing replication strategy on SimpleStrategy everything started to work.

Answer (score 3):

Just met same problem. check the keyspace's replication setting, if using NetworkTopologyStrategy, ensure the dc name is correct.

Answer (score 1):

To change replication strategy (from *NetworkTopologyStrategy*) to **SimpleStrategy** (which is proper for single node) run the following query:

```
ALTER KEYSPACE yourkeyspaceName WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it happened as one of the instance went down. Restarted the second instance and error gone. But in the schema table, I am seeing the Topology as Simple for my keyspace. That is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's clear the air here...

You **ABSOLUTELY** *can* use `NetworkTopologyStrategy` in a single-node configuration.  I currently have five versions of Cassandra installed on my local, and they are all configured that way, and they work just fine.

Albeit, it is not as simple as just using `SimpleStrategy`, so there are some steps that need to be taken:

Start by setting the `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` in the `cassandra.yaml`:

```
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

That tells Cassandra to use the `cassandra-rackdc.properties` file to name logical data centers and racks:

```
$ cat conf/cassandra-rackdc.properties | grep -v "#"

dc=dc1
rack=rack1
```

If you have a new cluster, you can change those.  If you have an existing cluster, leaving them is the best idea.  But you'll want to reference the `dc` name, because you'll need that in your keyspace definition.

Now, if you define your keyspace like this:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE stackoverflow WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1': '1'};
```

With this configuration, `NetworkTopologyStrategy` can be used just fine.

Opinions will differ on this, but I do not recommend using `SimpleStrategy`.  It's a good idea to practice getting used to using `NetworkTopologyStrategy` on your local.  I say this, because I have seen the opposite happen: folks accidentally deploy a `SimpleStrategy` keyspace into a MDHA cluster in production, and then wonder why their configured application consistency cannot be met.

Answer (score 0):

It happens some times when the node is down who is having the desired partition ranges for that insert. Please check your all nodes from below commands and try to run query again.

**nodetool status**

**nodetool describecluster.**